# how can i refresh a page other than the parent page from a popup on close of the popup window

Tags: jquery, html

I have an application that displays a schedule form with an assets header column across the top, a time column down the left side, and a table that users can click to produce a popup window with a form. On submission the newjobform closes and updates the parent page with this piece of code in the child form.

```
window.onunload = refreshParent;
function refreshParent() {
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;}
```

This works fine if the job is scheduled on the first try. However, if the user schedules a job that conflicts with another job, the form is reopened with attempted data and a notice of what job it conflicted with. This second popup window breaks the link to the parent page (schedule.php) and then does not refresh the schedule page. in cases of conflicts how can I force the reload of the schedule page from the submitted popup form?

Comment: My suggestion would be to write a ajax request that you can query to see if there is a conflict, before submission.

Comment: I have a check for conflicts based in my php, and that is what is going wrong with the refresh. A conflict must produce new information on the form page that the user can see and then alter the form while looking at the conflict information.

Comment: Right, what i'm saying is you need to move where those conflict checks are happening(on submit) so that you can be sure you have valid data before refreshing the page.

Comment: Sorry, I am not completely new to javascript but I have no experience with ajax. I am a php developer who is being forced to implement client side functionality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what I need to do was refresh the schedule page of the application when the first second or third etc.. popup is closed, the answer was to place this function on the parent 'schedule' page its self.

```
window.onblur= function() 
{window.onfocus= function () 
{
    location.reload(true)
}};
```

However, I don't know if this is going to cause a resend confirmation message do to the nature of POST...